# Can't import react-redux component in jest "TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test in jest for a component that uses react-redux but i am having an error related to the import. I believe it may be something with the way I export the component.

I created a dummy test without the import and it works normally. Only when I try to import the component that the error occurs

This is how the component is exported

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(WithPageLayout(DetailsMember));
```

and this is the simple test

```
import DetailsMember from './DetailsMember';

describe('form validator class', () => {
    it('initilizes constructor correctly', () => {
        const test = true;
        expect(test).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm, what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Comment: from which line of which file ? Are you sure the path `'./DetailsMember'` is correct ? Do you haver other tests file in your project that works correctly ?

Comment: yes, the path is correct. I have other tests working in the project, but they all have a simple import. This is the first test of a component that uses redux and hocs –

Answer (score 0):

You should include `import React from 'react';` in your test file as well.